# Rename existing tag in OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I created a photo tag name in OneDrive and after tagging many photos, I found a typo in the tag, that I'd like to correct.  How can I rename that tag?  Can it be done?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, as there doesn't appear to be an option, is this. This is for PC.
Pick one photo and add the correct tag then delete the old tag.
Next, open and multi-select all the wrongly tagged photos. 
Click the "i" top right of page, then click edit tags.
Scroll to the correct tag in the list on right and select the one you want. Hit X to remove the one you no longer need. 
WAIT for a moment (or longer if you have a slow PC /internet connection). Page will "grey out" while the tags are sorted.
Once done, hit X at top right and F5 to refresh / reload page with new tags.
Repeat as necessary.

I find doing more than 100 at a time is really slow and ineffective and I have fast PC and fast broadband.
Hope this helps.